# BigQuery ARRAY_TO_STRING based on condition in non-array field

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery, aggregate-functions

I have a table that I query like this...

```
select *
from table
where productId = 'abc123'
```

Which returns 2 rows (even though the productId is unique) because one of the columns (orderName) is an Array...

```
**productId, productName, created, featureCount, orderName**
abc123, someProductName, 2020-01-01, 12, someOrderName
      ,                ,           ,   , someOtherOrderName
```

I'm not sure whether the missing values in the 2nd row are empty strings or nulls because of the way the orderName array expands my search results but I want to now run a query like this...

```
select productName, ARRAY_TO_STRING(orderName,'-')
from table
where productId = 'abc123'
and ifnull(featureCount,0) > 0
```

But this query returns...

```
someProductName, someOrderName-someOtherOrderName
```

i.e. both array values came back even though I specified a condition of featureCount>0.

I'm sure I'm missing something very basic about how Arrays function in BigQuery but from Google's ARRAY_TO_STRING documentation I don't see any way to add a condition to the extracting of ARRAY values. Appreciate any thoughts on the best way to go about this.

Comment: see the json view of the result. It may clear your doubt whether it is NULL or '' (blank)

Comment: thanks for the tip @Mr.Batra - the json view just shows the other fields are not arrays.  So I see {"productId":"abc123", "productName":"someProductName", "created":"2020-01-01", "featureCount":12,"orderName":["someOrderName","someOtherOrderName"]}

Comment: Which means feature count 12 is tied with one array which looks like this ["someOrderName","someOtherOrderName"].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I understand, this is because you are just querying one row of data which have a column as `ARRAY<STRING>`. As you are using `ARRAY_TO_STRINGS` it will only accept `ARRAY<STRING>` values you will see all array values fit into just one cell.

So, when you run your script, your output will fit your criteria and return the columns with arrays with additional rows for visibility.

The visualization on the UI should look like your mention in your question:

| Row | productId | productName | created | featureCount | orderName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc123 | someProductName | 2020-01-01 | 12 | someOrderName |
|  |  |  |  |  | someOtherOrderName |

**Note**: On bigquery this additional row is gray out (   ) and Its part of row 1 but it shows as an additional row for visibility. So this output only have 1 row in the table.

And the visualization on a JSON will be:

```
[
  {
    "productId": "abc123",
    "productName": "someProductName",
    "created": "2020-01-01",
    "featureCount": "12",
    "orderName": [
      "someOrderName",
      "someOtherOrderName"
    ]
  }
]
```

I don't think there is specific documentation info about how you visualize arrays on UI but I can share the docs that talks about how to `flattening` your rows outputs into a single row line, check:

- [Working with Arrays](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays)
- [Flattening Arrays](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#flattening_arrays)

I use the following to replicate your issue:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `project-id.dataset.working_table` (
 productId STRING,
 productName STRING,
 created STRING,
 featureCount STRING,
 orderName ARRAY<STRING>
);

insert into `project-id.dataset.working_table` (productId,productName,created,featureCount,orderName) 
values ('abc123','someProductName','2020-01-01','12',['someOrderName','someOtherOrderName']);
 
insert into `project-id.dataset.working_table` (productId,productName,created,featureCount,orderName) 
values ('abc123X','someProductNameX','2020-01-02','15',['someOrderName','someOtherOrderName','someData']);
```

output

| Row | productId | productName | created | featureCount | orderName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc123 | someProductName | 2020-01-01 | 12 | someOrderName |
|  |  |  |  |  | someOtherOrderName |
| 2 | abc123X | someProductNameX | 2020-01-02 | 15 | someOrderName |
|  |  |  |  |  | someOtherOrderName |
|  |  |  |  |  | someData |

**Note**: Table contains 2 rows.